# ¿Cómo llamar un método creado dentro de una clase?

Tags: javascript

He declarado dos funciones dentro de una clase llamada `users`, ahora necesito ejecutar las funciones y mostrar en consola el resultado, como podría hacer esto?

trate esto:

```
console.log(users.full_name());
```

Claro que no funciona porque esto seria para objetos no para clases. o tendría que crear un objeto de la clase para llamar la función ?

Gracias por la ayuda

```js
var name = prompt("Ingrese su nombre");
var last_name = prompt("Ingrese su apellido");
var email = prompt("Ingrse su email");
var age = parseInt(prompt("ingrese su edad"));

class users {
    constructor (name, last_name, email, age){
        this.name = name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.email = email;
        this.age = age;
    }

    
    is_adult(){
        age > 18 ? true : false;
    }

    full_name(){
        return this.name + this.last_name;
    }
}

//Nuevo objeto de la clase users
my_info = new users(name, last_name, email, age);
alert("Su nombre es " + my_info.name + " Su apellido es " + my_info.last_name + " Su email es " + my_info.email + " su edad es " + age);

console.log(users.full_name());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es correcto como tratas de acceder debido a que:

- El método `full_name` no es estático, por lo tanto la clase no puede directamente acceder a el
- El objeto creado en el proceso de instancia es el que si puede acceder a las propiedades y métodos de tu clase
- Lo que debes usar entonces es el objeto creado que se llama: `full_name`

Quedando de esta forma:

```
console.log(my_info.full_name());
```

Por otro lado la sintaxis que tratas de manejar debe considerar lo siguiente:

- Evita entonces el uso del contructor ya que este requeriría de la instancia
- En su lugar declara un método propio que reciba parámetros y que este mismo sea estático
- Te vales del método estático que tu mismo declaras y cuando lo invocas por medio de la sintaxis de: `Clase.método` le pasas los argumentos necesarios para asignarlos a los parámetros que anteriormente declaraste.

Un ejemplo:

```
class Demo {
  static registraUsuario (val1, val2) {
    return val1+val2     
  }
}

console.log(Demo.registraUsuario("Hugo y ", "Paco"))
```